# Vue js переопределение константы

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
const default_row = {
    series: 1,
    season: 1
};

var vm = new Vue({
    el: '.wrapper',
    data: {
        cols: {},
        id: window.location.href.split('#')[1] || 0,
        loader: true,
        showModal: false,
        add_row: default_row,
        rows: {},
        col_names: []
    },
    mounted: function () {
//        next(self.videos, self.id)
    },
    methods: {
        add: function (data) {
            var self = this;
            if (Object.size(self.add_row) != 4) {
                alert('НЕ ВСЕ ПОЛЯ ЗАПОЛНЕНЫ');
                c('НЕ ВСЕ ПОЛЯ ЗАПОЛНЕНЫ', moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
                validInput();
                return false;
            }
            inValid();
            self.loader = true;
            $.ajax({
                url: "php/data.php",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {act: 'add', data: self.add_row, user: self.user_id},
                success: function (data) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(data);
                    if (typeof data.error == 'undefined') {
                        self.add_row = default_row;
                        c(default_row) //здесь косяк
                        vm.refresh();
                    } else {
                        alert(data.error.errorInfo);
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        },
})
```

я ожидаю что применится дефолтное значение, а на этом этапе данные что я ввел

т.е. есть форма ввода, после отправки на сервер нужно привести к исходному виду, но константа как - то поменялась

Comment: как то не понимаю что значит `на этом этапе`? последняя строка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы объект сделали константой, свойства внутри этого объекта не защищены от изменения.